# dispatcher not defined when importing module

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, python-import, mlxtend

I was attempting to import some modules in a Spyder IDE:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ExhaustiveFeatureSelector
```

For both of the import statements above I get the error:

`"NameError: name 'dispatcher' is not defined"`

Tried install package "dispatcher"

Comment: A `ModuleNotFoundError` or `ImportError` might indicate that you need to install a package called "dispatcher". But you're not getting that. You're getting a `NameError`, which indicates a different kind of problem. This problem is internal to some code or other that references the symbol `dispatcher` without first assigning it. Examine the backtrace of the error to determine which statement or expression, on which line of which file, is throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but while using [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html). I managed to track the error to [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), I was using version 1.15. I updated numpy to version 1.17.3 and the issue was solved. If you are using conda, you can do so by typing

`conda update numpy=1.17.3`

on the Anaconda prompt.